# Why is intuitionistic logic called that?

Tags: logic, terminology

I've heard some sources say "it is the logic that formalizes Brouwer's mathematical programme of intuitionism", but that still doesn't explain where the name "intuitionism" came from. Nothing about it seems particularly intuitive, and it I'd argue the lack of $P \lor \lnot P$ and $\lnot \lnot P \to P$ is rather *un*intuitive. Is there some key detail I am missing, or is this just one of those not-very-descriptive names?

Comment: Looking here -- https://www.etymonline.com/word/intuitive#:~:text=intuitive%20(adj.),a%20word%20of%20uncertain%20origin., it seems like there is an older definition of the word "intuitive" which better aligns with its use here: "perceiving directly and immediately".

Comment: Do you know how intuitionism contrasts with platonism and formalism?  Specifically, regarding the question "what does it mean to say a statement is true?"  I find that context most appropriate for thinking about its name.

Comment: $(P \to Q) \lor (Q \to P)$ seems a counterintuitive consequence of $P \lor \lnot P$ but is not really the point.  Intuitionism was a reaction against Cantor's hierarchy of infinities and the contradictions of naive set theory, instead trying to base mathematics on the intuitions of the natural numbers and finite proofs, with the thought that if a solution to a question could be constructed then this was more secure than situations where it could not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a question about mathematics, so I voted to close. I'll answer the question nonetheless, but the answer will have to consist entirely of history and (quite difficult, and on top of it superficially summarized) philosophy.

As you point out, intuitionistic logic got its name specifically from Brouwer's intuitionist philosophy (distinct from e.g. Poincare's intuitionism, which was based on Kant's concept of intuition).

So why did Brouwer's intuitionism get that name? Well, it was named after the "first act of intuition" that Brouwer describes e.g. in his [Cambridge lectures](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521177367).

According to Brouwer's account, at the heart of mathematical thought is the experience of observing a moment in time transition into another: one moment giving way to another, with the first moment being retained in memory. This perception is what's abstracted into what Brouwer refers to as the abstract concept of *twoity*. Brouwer claims that this abstracted form of two-ness represents the *fundamental intuition* upon which all of mathematics is built, and in Brouwer's view, it is from this basic intuition that all other mathematical concepts should be constructed. And this fundamental intuition is what gives intuitionism its name.

As for whether intuitionistic logic is intuitive or not: that's hardly relevant to the nomenclature. After all, it's **not** called *intuitive logic*.

Comment: Your answer is very interesting, so I am glad that the question wasn't closed :)

Comment: "This is not a question about mathematics, so I voted to close":

I've heard intuitionism referred to as a "mathematical programme" before, so :shrug:

Comment: And I also agree with your statement "As for whether intuitionistic logic is intuitive or not: that's hardly relevant to the nomenclature"; I was merely making an educated guess at the origin given the same root word.